# Product won't uninstall from windows when uninstalling previous product during its installation

Tags: windows-installer, installation, installshield, uninstallation, basic-msi

I have an Installshield Basic MSI installer that installs the new version of our product. If the user is still on the old version (installed by an Installscript installer), the installer will execute the uninstall string of the old product before proceeding to install the new product.

This is causing some issue when the user goes to uninstall the new version of our product. When going to add/remove programs and running the uninstaller, the uninstaller runs and removes the files, however when refreshing the add/remove list, the product appears still to be installed. The files have been removed, yet there are remnants of the product in the registry.

The only way to effectively uninstall the product is through a 3rd party registry cleaner(and possibly a script built off of this). The odd thing is that if the user uninstalls the old product manually before installing the new, uninstallation of the new product will work fine. Also, installing the new product without the old product ever being on the machine will result in a clean uninstall as well.

The 2 products have different product codes. Any ideas what could be causing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If anything is showing in Add/Remove programs as not being uninstalled, then the registry key located here is still in place:

```
HTLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall/{ProductGUID or Name}
```

or for 64 bit systems:

```
HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall/{ProductGUID or Name}
```

In the uninstall portion of the *new* package make sure they:

1. Do not have the same Product ID (you already stated that but make sure ;) )
2. If needed, add a line inside the code to delete the registry entries that are left over.

You can nest files into Installshield and Wise package studio. You can write a .bat file, drop it in the temp directory, code it so when ran it deletes the last bit left over ex. the registry keys.

OR

Create a virtual machine, install the new product, capture it with Wise and deploy it that way.

Without seeing the code inside your Installshield I have no clue what detailed explanations I can give....

GL !!!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've tried deleting the entries at the Uninstall registry path that you mentioned, which removes it from the add/remove programs list for good, however, when I go to re-install the product the installer launches in maintenance mode, as if the product is still installed.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably calling the old product uninstall string in the middle of the new product installation. The MSI installation script logs all changes, and also includes the "uninstalling old" changes. When you are uninstalling the new product, these changes get reverted, so MSI restores the registry entries that existed before it started to install. These entries include the old product uninstall entries.

I know little about InstallShield Basic MSI mode. If it has some ability to change installation sequence or to set when your actions are executed, then you should make sure that uninstallation of the old product happens between InstallValidate and InstallInitialize standard actions. If InstallShield does not give you such control, you will probably have to ask your users to uninstall an old version manually.

See this article on uninstall actions placement:
http://jpassing.com/2007/06/16/where-to-place-removeexistingproducts-in-a-major-msi-upgrade/

Comment: Thanks BBR. This sounds like it might work. I'll try out messing with the custom actions sequence tomorrow.

Comment: Hi BBR, I tried kicking off the uninstaller between InstallValidate and InstallInitialize with no success. The uninstallation of the old product and installation of the new product succeeds, but the uninstallation of the new product still leaves remnants.

Comment: Do you have a full verbose logs of the install and uninstall runs? Look into them and try to understand when these registry entries are affected.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you haven't properly set the upgrade mechanism in your new installer. Perhaps you chose "Install setup then remove unneeded files" on item from Upgrade menu.
If so, change it to "Remove old setup first" and check out that you use proper UpgradeCode. 
Or just create a new Upgrade item special for previous version of installer, with removing it before installation.